# How to determine the upstream and downstream part of a catchment?

Tags: clustering, catchment

I have around 20 000 topographic depressions in a catchment. I want to perform cluster analysis on them in several round. In a first round, I want to cluster them in two clusters: depressions upstream (1) and downstream (2) in the catchment.
I have several variables of the topographic depressions, two of them being the min elevation and max elevation of the depressions.

Which other variables can I use in this cluster analysis? What are good suggestions?

Comment: Which software?

Comment: @Nikos I use R Studio and QGIS

Comment: What data and in what format do you have? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example